# previous row value in data table in Spotfire

Tags: arrays, row, calculated-columns, spotfire

This is super easy in excel.. Couldn't find it this in Spotfire easily.. Quick help would be appreciated.

Question:

In the calculated column, I like to add previous row data.
For example, in attached sheet calculated column "Previous CODE". I like add data of Column "CODE" from previous row.

Please let me know incase something is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this with a calculated column having the expression:

```
First([CODE]) OVER Previous([EVENT_DATE])
```